# better method for serving files on nodejs server instead of if/else

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an endpoint that serves a file for the user to download based on the user's selections on the webpage. However, based on the possibilities of the users selections, the only way I can think of to account for it all is by using if/else statements.

```
router.post('/process', function(req, res) {
    if(req.query.os == 'Windows' && req.query.rec == 'Computer Information' && req.query.report == 'Local Report') {
        res.send('http://localhost:3033/proc/windows/info/local/files.zip');
    } else if (req.query.os == 'Windows' && req.query.rec == 'User Information' && req.query.report == 'Local Report') {
        res.send('http://localhost:3033/proc/windows/uinfo/local/files.zip');
    }
}
```

If I add options for Linux or OSX, ill have to account for those as well and, as a result the code will become very long and ugly. Is there a better way for me to account for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could *translate* your variables into url parts. It will be easier to maintain. For example:

```
router.post('/process', function(req, res) {
    var url_parts = {
        'os' : {
            'Windows' : 'windows',
            'Linux' : 'linux',
            'OSX' : 'mac'
        },
        'rec' : {
            'Computer Information' : 'info',
            'User Information' : 'uinfo'
        },
        'report' : {
            'Local Report' : 'local',
            'Global Report' : 'global'
        }
    };

    res.send(
        'http://localhost:3033/proc/'
        + url_parts.os[req.query.os]
        + '/' + url_parts.rec[req.query.rec]
        + '/' + url_parts.report[req.query.report]
        + '/files.zip'
        );
});
```